# JS initialize section error, Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm having 'quirky' (things that pop up, that are to me unexplainable) in my code. 
Currently my main js.script is the fullpage.js script => [Fullpage js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

I really love the script. though the error bugs me ;). 
The github responded that the error didn't lay with the fullpage.js. Kinda strange I thought because it is the main .js script I have.

So now I'm stuck on my own to find out what the problem is, and there's where the problem lays.
I now at this moment haven't got the sufficient knowledge to troubleshoot my problem.

What I presume is either a double line of code in my css to js or a general double line in my fullpage.js.

You can see a clear repeating error on my site when you scroll one page down, then one slider left (or more), scroll up again and you see a turquoise rectangle appearing. Often when refreshing the site you see a turquoise background. 
the link to my site => http://theoctopushideaway.nz/

=> EDIT: THE TURQUOISE IS FIXED, THOUGH THE RECTANGLE REMAINS BUT NOT IN A SAME REPEATING FREQUENCY. EVER SO OFTEN VERTICAL STRIPES APPEAR AS WELL.

I know it's better to show a snippet of code rather than the site, but in this case I don't know where to search or what to show except the whole site. Incase of an answer I can show the code for others having similar question. (And perhaps adjust my title as well, based on the fact it's not that clear).

Please by mild with me (but not to much), I'm learning everyday and trial and error way works best for me until now. Hope you can point me in the direction of how to troubleshoot the errors.

And I know there more problems with my site (Too big a photo's as for one example) but first things first I assume, getting my core code to work.
Though if you have constructive tips, please be welcome to share them.

I think I said it all or at least I hope so.

And let the noob bashing begin.

Comment: Hit F12. Full of errors - for example animate.js loaded before the jQuery itt needs

Comment: Are you talking about the turquoise background? Is that your "quirky"?

Comment: Hit F12 in dreamweaver or in the browser? I'm running on mac now, will start my bootcamp and test that out. Its kind of a debug feature then? thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at your fullPage.js initialization you will easily see that you are telling fullPage.js to use that turquoise color:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: true,
    sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#myMenu'
});
```

Take a look at this:

```
sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
```

Just delete that line if you don't want to add any background color, its explained in the docs:

> **sectionsColor:** (default none) Define the CSS background-color property for each section: Example:

Comment: The color is gone, but the rectangle remains but not in a repeating frequency.

Comment: @Qinten it is not a rectangle. It is the background of your page. What else would you like to see instead? That's going to happen in any site. Your image is very big and takes time to load, meanwhile, whatever is under your image will be shown. Nothing to do with fullPage.js.

Comment: Resizing my photo's didn't help. The white square at the top left appears and the vertical strip appears with the same movements. 
there must be indeed something in the background that shows. But each pictures dimensions and handling time is minimal for website, thus it should load quicker. And it does actually, but still the error comes back. 
Could it be the order of my javascript fetch links? Or do my Leaflet.js make bugs with the fullpage.js.
And when I debug (developer tool in chrome), and click the rectangle, it doesn't show me the line of code that shows me the rectangle

Comment: I don't think you are talking about any rectangle... you are just talking about the background of the website which shows when your picture is loading. (which btw, is quite heavy...). Before it was turquoise, now that you removed it, its white. That's totally logical.

Comment: Hmm? I could definitely be wrong. But my background pictures al have 1920x* (1028to1440) and in size of date are around 356 kb. I think that's not very much to load. The rectangle I see is by my view (Imac27inch) around h390px x w200px and it doesn't vary in size on my screen, the bottom strip I see does vary in size of height, mainly between 20px and 60px. 
The fact of the turquoise and now the white I completely get. That was actually a no brainer ^^, my apologies for that in fact. 

And my problem does not occur in the beginning of loading the page.

Comment: I see an horizontal scrolling bar in your site. That's creating a gap between the 1st section and the 2nd one. If that's what you mean.

Comment: Then you are using `background-attachment: fixed;` I have no idea with what intention, which might cause some weird behaviors.

Comment: Yeah the background fixed is something I used to display my logo, because when I removed it it didn't show my logo anymore. Though! the rectangle and strip is removed. Thanks! I'll search for a different way to get my logo to show.